# How to set these two different images using position in android?

Tags: android, position, imageview

I have two different images and would like to set them using different views but overlap slightly to match the below images. I also want to be able to set a different `OnClickListener` for each of them. I know with iOS I can set the view positions using `x` and `y` values but I'm not sure how to do this in Android.

How can I go about doing this?

Desired result:

[image]

Image One

[image]

Image Two

[image]

Comment: i will try in relative layout_alignofright already but is not perfectly work

Comment: tried to add a negative margin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try set those two images as `ImageView`'s and put them inside a `FrameLayout`. That way you can set them as you want, So they can overlap one another. That way you can set an `clickable` and `onClick` properties for both of them separately:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iFirstImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/sort_image_1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="setFirstImageClick"
    android:src="@drawable/sort_image_1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iSecondImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/sort_image_2"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="setSecondImageClick"
    android:src="@drawable/sort_image_2" />
```

And create methods `setFirstImageClick` and `setSecondImageClick` in your activity to decide what each image click should do.

Comment: how can i set two image for different screen resolution if image size is different

Answer (score 0):

You can place the first image however you want, and then in the xml for the second image use

```
android:layout_toRightOf="firstImageId"
```

You can set each onClick separately after that.